# sparql: how to avoid visited subject

Tags: sparql

and I am trying to write SPARQL query to find distinct object.

here is the dataset:

```
<https://permid.org/1-36436064275> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <https://permid.org/1-34414203048> .

<https://permid.org/1-34414203048> <http://permid.org/ontology/person/hasTenureInOrganization> <https://permid.org/1-36436064275> .
```

my sparql query is like this:

```
select distinct ?n where {

      <https://permid.org/1-36436064275> ?a ?b .
      ?b ?c ?d . 
      ?d ?e ?n .                     
}
```

From the dataset, "?d" is https://permid.org/1-36436064275, which is the visited subject. I want to skip visited subject, so that "?d" is empty, thus "?n" is also empty.

Comment: Your rdf data looks strange, you have a weird cycle in your graph: resource A has a type B, but then B is (apparently) a person who has tenure in an organisation, which is A again. So, if `1-36436064275` is an organisation, and  `1-34414203048` is a person, how can the organisation be a kind of person? That sounds wrong.

Comment: A further tip: from how you're phrasing your question I'm inferring that you are approaching this as some kind of graph traversal problem. I would recommend that instead of "just" thinking about the graph, you think about the knowledge that is captured in that graph. Think about what the purpose of your query is, in terms of the knowledge that you're trying to obtain from your data (e.g. a query to retrieve "people who have tenure" rather than "distinct objects", "visited nodes" and "edges followed").

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to address here:

> From the dataset, "?d" is https://permid.org/1-36436064275, which is the visited subject.

This happens because your RDF graph is a cycle. The first bit of your SPARQL query is:

```
<https://permid.org/1-36436064275> ?a ?b .
```

This binds `?a` to `rdf:type`, and `?b` to  `1-34414203048`. The second part of your query pattern is:

```
?b ?c ?d .
```

Since `?b` is already bound to `1-34414203048` by the previous pattern, there's only one option for `?c` (`hasTenureInOrganization`) and `?d` (`1-36436064275`). Then the third bit of your query is:

```
?d ?e ?n .
```

`?d` is already bound by the previous pattern, so there's one option for `?e` (`rdf:type` again) and `?n` (`1-36436064275` again).

> I want to skip visited subject, so that "?d" is empty, thus "?n" is
>   also empty.

That's not how SPARQL works. SPARQL only returns a query result if the *entire* pattern has a result. If `?n` has no value, the query will return an empty result.

Having said that, if you want to ensure that `?d` is never equal to the subject that you started your query with, you could simply add a FILTER condition:

```
FILTER (?d != <https://permid.org/1-36436064275>)
```

But, like I said in the comments as well, I think you may need to rethink your data model a little bit, and consider the purpose of your query as well.